# Doctrine DQL add raw SQL?

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a DQL query object which we've implemented (copying a legacy application). The output has to match the legacy verbatim.

The static fields worked like a charm - but now we've encountered more complex computed fields, such as:

```
IF(
                wo.date_approved = 0,
                0,
                IF(
                    ship.date_shipped > wo.date_approved,
                    ROUND(
                        IF(
                            (ship.date_shipped - wo.date_approved) > wo.time_inactive,
                            (ship.date_shipped - wo.date_approved) - wo.time_inactive,
                            ship.date_shipped - wo.date_approved
                        ) / 86400, 2),
                    0
                )
            ) AS TAT,
```

This is not possible to express using the query builder/DQL. I had hoped to possibly adjust the query right before execution (after parameters have been bound but before execution).

Using a placeholder or similar I would search and replace that with the series of computed fields...

I can't figure out a way to make this happen?!?! :o

Alex

Comment: You can just use sql and avoid dql altogether for these sorts of queries.  If you really need objects then you might need to write your own hydrator but for most report type stuff, just stick with an array often works well.

Comment: That may be required...but we have a substantial amount of code written using the DQL builder - hopefully switching to the DBAL query builder is straight forward.